# php sdk of google Firestore throw error "Google\Firestore\V1beta1\StructuredQuery\CollectionSelector" not found when try to retrieve data

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

im have installed the php sdk of google fire store "google/cloud-firestore"
when i try to pull data from the collection it throws this error

> Uncaught Error: Class 'Google\Firestore\V1beta1\StructuredQuery\CollectionSelector' not found in vendor/google/gax/src/Serializer.php:276

my actual code is

```
// custom logic, just pulling the config array this part is working fine   
$option = $ins->integration('firebase')->get_options();
       
$firestore = new FirestoreClient($option);
$chats =  $firestore->collection('chats'); // this is where the error occurred
```

full error trace is

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Google\Firestore\V1beta1\StructuredQuery\CollectionSelector' not found in /vendor/google/gax/src/Serializer.php:276
Stack trace:
#0 /vendor/google/gax/src/Serializer.php(314): Google\GAX\Serializer->decodeElement(Object(Google\Protobuf\FieldDescriptor), Array)
#1 /vendor/google/gax/src/Serializer.php(103): Google\GAX\Serializer->decodeMessageImpl(Object(Google\Firestore\V1beta1\StructuredQuery), Object(Google\Protobuf\Descriptor), Array)
#2 /vendor/google/cloud-firestore/Connection/Grpc.php(168): Google\GAX\Serializer->decodeMessage(Object(Google\Firestore\V1beta1\StructuredQuery), Array)
#3 /vendor/google/cloud-firestore/Query.php(166): Google\Cloud\Firestore\Connection\Grpc-> in /vendor/google/gax/src/Serializer.php on line 276
```

in the Serializer class the function that throws the error is this

```
private function decodeElement(FieldDescriptor $field, $data)
    {
        switch ($field->getType()) {
            case GPBType::MESSAGE:
                if ($data instanceof \Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message) {
                    return $data;
                }
                $messageType = $field->getMessageType();
                $klass = $messageType->getClass();
                
                $msg = new $klass();   // this class is not found 'Google\Firestore\V1beta1\StructuredQuery\CollectionSelector'

                return $this->decodeMessageImpl($msg, $messageType, $data);
            default:
                return $data;
        }
    }
```

i dumped the $klass and $data variable and this is the output

```
string(59) "Google\Firestore\V1beta1\StructuredQuery\CollectionSelector"
array(1) {
  ["collectionId"]=>
  string(5) "chats"
}
```

Comment: Have you followed all of the steps described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#php), specially [this one](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#php_1)? This might the cause of the issue you are facing.

Comment: yes, i followed the docs as much as possible, if you are referring to use the "use \Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;", i already did, the object is initiating , the problem is that "\V1beta1\StructuredQuery\CollectionSelector" class does not exist

Answer (score 1):

its really weird but i just deleted vendor dir, and re run composer with --no-cache flag and now its working